# expl3: How to add a clist-grouping brace to a tokenlist?

Tags: expl3, latex3, braces

I have LaTeX3 code for a macro that processes its parameters in a complicated way and builds a tree-like structure. To represent this structure it constructs a comma-separated list of strings and comma-separated lists (e.g. `a,{b,c}`). It does not use the clist interface, but adds brackets and strings to a tokenlist that is processed with `\clist_new:NV` later.

My problem is: I have no idea how to add a single curly bracket to a tokenlist without unbalancing the code. I tried it with `\c_group_begin_token` and `\c_group_end_token` but they did not expand to braces.

How to add clist-grouping braces to a tokenlist?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{mmm}{
  \cs_new:Nn \__begin_bracket: {[}  
  \cs_new:Nn \__end_bracket: {]}  
  %\cs_new:Nn \__begin_bracket: {\c_group_begin_token}  
  %\cs_new:Nn \__end_bracket: {\c_group_begin_token} 

  % This processing is more complicated in reality.
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1 , }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\__begin_bracket:}
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2 , }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#3}
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\__end_bracket:}

  \tl_log:N \l_tmpa_tl

  \clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
    \tl_log:n {##1}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\foo{a}{b}{c}
\end{document}
```

When altering `\__begin_bracket:` and `\__end_bracket:` the output in the logfile should be:

```
\l_tmpa_tl=a,{b,c}.
a.
b,c.
```

**Note:** In a previous version of this question I used brackets around the whole list. This does not work with `\clist_set:NV` (it assumes I want to escape the comma with the braces).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have unbalanced token lists; you can use a small trick, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \khb_left_brace:  { { \if_false: } \fi: }
\cs_new:Nn \khb_right_brace: { \if_false: { \fi: } }

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mmm}{

  % This processing is more complicated in reality.
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\exp_not:n {#1 ,} }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\khb_left_brace:}
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\exp_not:n {#2 ,} }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\exp_not:n {#3} }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\khb_right_brace:}

  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }

  \tl_log:N \l_tmpa_tl

  \clist_set:NV \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
    \tl_log:n {##1}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\foo{a}{b}{c}
\end{document}
```

The log file has

```
> \l_tmpa_tl=a,{b,c}.
> a.
> b,c.
```

as expected

Comment: Thanks. I don't need the `\exp_not:n` if my arguments are not expandable. Correct?

Comment: @K-HB Yes, but since you need to do an x-expansion anyway, it doesn't hurt and is safer in case your arguments become something else. Define syntactic sugar such as `\cs_new_protected:Nn \khb_tl_partial_put:Nn { \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { \exp_not:n { #2 } } }`

Comment: The last line of the log shows it didn't really work (only one list-item). I found my mistake in the MWE. Please see at the new note in the question.

Comment: @K-HB It *does* work according to the proposed code. The outer braces should not be added, if you want a two item list. Fixed.

Comment: So the mistake was in my MWE. It didn't fit to my question.